# In React how to create input fields and change current items in a row?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, axios

I have a parent and a child components. There creates a table with data. I have a modify icon in every row of a table. Now I need when this icon is clicked - there were created input fields for this particular row and this data can be modified, then if pressed "Ok" - pass this changed data to database with "axios.put" method, and if pressed "cancel" - do note modify item. 
I created isInEditMode variable. But I don't know where to create that input fields, in child or in parent?

Child:

```
import React from 'react';
import './tableHasp.css';


class TableHasp extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return  ( 
      <tr>
         <td>{ this.props.hasps._id}</td>
         <td>{ this.props.hasps.serial }</td>
         <td>{ this.props.hasps.soft }</td>
         <td>{ this.props.hasps.numberOfKeys }</td>
         <td>{ this.props.hasps.company.name }</td>
         <td>{ this.props.hasps.company.city }</td>
         <td>{ this.props.hasps.company.phone }</td>
         <td>{ this.props.hasps.dateCreated }</td>
         <td><i onClick={() => this.props.modifyEvent(this.props.hasps)} className="far fa-edit btnEdit"></i></td>
         <td><i  onClick={() => this.props.delEvent(this.props.hasps._id)} className="far fa-trash-alt btnDelete" ></i></td>
      </tr>
      );
  }
}

export default TableHasp;
```

Parent data for child:

```
<div className="container">
        <table className="table table-striped">
        <thead className="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">id</th>
            <th scope="col">Serial Number</th>
            <th scope="col">Soft</th>
            <th scope="col">Number of Keys</th>
            <th scope="col">Company</th>
            <th scope="col">City</th>
            <th scope="col">Contacts</th>
            <th scope="col">Date Created</th>
            <th scope="col">Edit</th>
            <th scope="col">Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
         <tbody>
            {this.state.hasps.map((hasp, i) => 
            <TableHasp 
                 delEvent={(hasp) => this.deleteCurrentHaspInfo(hasp)} 
                 modifyEvent={(id) => this.modifyCurrentHaspInfo(id)}  
                 key={i} 
                 hasps={hasp} 
                 />)}
          </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
```

Function that will modify item data:

```
 modifyCurrentHaspInfo = (hasp) => { 
    this.setState({
      isInEditMode: !this.state.isInEditMode,
      editHasp: hasp
    })   
    console.log(hasp); 
     // if (prompt("Enter password:") === "123456") {
        axios.put("/hasp/change", 
            {
              _id: hasp._id,
              serial: "yyyyy-99000",  //test data
              soft: "test-put3"       //test data
            }            
         )
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);      
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        })
     // } else {
      //  alert("Wrong password!");
     // }         
   }
```

Comment: You should save the info of each row, and check if its editing. If editing, render an input with the value that you had. If it is not editing, render a simple div. I'll recomend you create a custom components, it will be easy

Comment: in parent optional `th` and in child optional `td` also pass `inEditMode` as prop to `TableHasp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Send the **index** instead of the **object***

```
<td><i onClick={() => this.props.modifyEvent(i)} className="far fa-edit btnEdit"></i></td>
```

*Modify the value, and add the prop in item.*

```
modifyCurrentHaspInfo = (index) => { 
  const hasps = [...this.state.hasps];
  hasps[index].isInEditMode = true;

  this.setState({hasps});

  console.log(hasp); 
  // if (prompt("Enter password:") === "123456") {

  axios.put("/hasp/change", 
        {
          _id: hasp._id,
          serial: "yyyyy-99000",  //test data
          soft: "test-put3"       //test data
        }            
     )
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);      
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
   // } else {
   //  alert("Wrong password!");
  // }         
}
```

*Create a new  with the condition.*

```
{this.props.hasps.isInEditMode && <td>ACTION!!!</td>}
```

***IMPORTANT***

Do not use ***INDEX as a key***

```
{this.state.hasps.map((hasp, i) => 
        <TableHasp 
             delEvent={(hasp) => this.deleteCurrentHaspInfo(hasp)} 
             modifyEvent={(hasps) => this.modifyCurrentHaspInfo(hasps)}  
             key={i} 
             hasps={hasp} 
             />
)}
```

Use a unique value from the object.

**Why you should not use index as a key.**

> A key is the only thing React uses to identify DOM elements. What happens if you push an item to the list or remove something in the middle? If the key is same as before React assumes that the DOM element represents the same component as before. But that is no longer true.

Source: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318